# Best practices for filesystem stored in a file

Tags: linux, ext4, xfs

For GDPR purposes, I will need to setup encrypted filesystem on my server.

My server comes with single partition formatted as XFS - this is stock I can not change this.

I plan to do big file 1TB or so and to encrypt it with LUKS. Then I will format it with XFS or EXT4.

If machine is accidentally reboot, someone will need to login and unlock LUKS.

Is there some consideration about this setup?

Also should I use XFS or EXT4 for filesystem stored in a file?

Comment: Whats the reason for not just changing partitioning?

Comment: @anx You can't shrink an XFS filesystem.